# Want to send some param in Router to the next component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I have a requirement to call a component on call a next button, before that i need to validate the input made in the first page and while calling to the next component i want to pass Name element to the next component

I am using Router and trying to pass a value in the Router to the next component.

I have merged "onClick={(evnt) => this.onSubmit(evnt)}"  and "exact to="/AddModule" but this is not working, its only validating and calling the next component but that value i am trying to pass, is not happening

```
class Header extends React.Component{

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
        this.state={
            projectName: '',
            }
    }   

    onSubmit (evnt){
        evnt.preventDefault();
        console.log("calling submit method from on Click");
        const error = this.validate();  //This is the method which will do the validation
        console.log(this.state);
        if(error){
            alert("cannot be submitted, as contains error");
        }
        if(!error){
                this.setState({
                    projectName: '',
                    description: '',
                    errors : {}
                })
            }
    };

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                // Input Field

                    <Router>
                        <div>
                            <NavLink className="normal" activeClassName="active" onClick={(evnt) => this.onSubmit(evnt)} exact to="/AddModule">Next</NavLink>
                            <Route exact path='/AddModule' render={(props) => (
                              <AddModule {...props} Name='hi' />
                            )}/>
                        </div>
                    </Router>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Just to clarify, do u need to redirect to another component after submitting of input field, and pass value from this field as parameter?

Comment: No not exactly the value from the field, but some other value....like suppose i want to render to a different Tab, then that Tab Name i want to pass

Comment: could you show that piece of code where you try to pass tabName value?

Comment: You'll have to manually route to the next component. You should use `this.props.history.push('/AddModule/name')`. Unless I'm misunderstanding the question?